# 1099-int concern, tax filing

Tags: taxation, bonds, interest

My credit union issued me a 1099-int for savings bonds that were cashed in 2023.  Is it correct to say that box 3 of the 1099-int be the total of the interest earned plus half the face value of the bond?  This is the explanation the credit union gave to me, when I questioned why the had such a high interest amount on the 1099-int.

Comment: This question will be more appropriate at https://money.stackexchange.com/